# Finding the number of ways of distributing 15 things among 3 groups.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can $15$ different things be divided into three
>   groups containing $7,5$ and $3$ things.

According to me it should be $3! \times  ^{15}C_7 \times ^8C_5\times ^3C_3 =2162160 $ (note: $3!$ occurs to include the possibility of different groups (say GroupA , Group B , Group C) getting any particular combination ($7,5$ or $3$))

But answer given is $360360$.

Please tell me the fault in my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the multinomial coefficient
$$\frac{15!}{7!5!3!}$$
which indeed is $360360$. You have inflated the total by a factor $3!$
by adding labels to the three subsets (presumably not asked for in the
question).

Comment: But that is a possibility. WHy not include that?

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that the groups are indistinguishable?

Comment: @Abcd Of course they are distinguishable; they have different sizes.

Comment: Then why no multiplication by $3!$?

Comment: @Abcd If you do $\binom{15}{7}\binom{8}{5}\binom{3}{3}$, it already takes into account all possible options.